# Programmatically using the AWS CLI to determine whether an Amazon Redshift cluster is deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-cli

Pretty much as the title says, would like to find out when a Redshift cluster has been deleted. I'm using this from CI/CD, the prior command is to delete the cluster and I would like to automate more functionality following this check.

Current thinking is to use the `describe-cluster` endpoint and checking to see whether `ClusterNotFound` is in the string. Example response from a deleted cluster:

```
An error occurred (ClusterNotFound) when calling the DescribeClusters operation: Cluster <name> not found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `describe-clusters` and check the output to make sure the required cluster is not there.

You can do this with a combination of the [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/redshift/describe-clusters.html) and [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
if [[ $(aws redshift describe-clusters | jq '[.Clusters[].ClusterIdentifier] | any(contains("<name>"))') == "true" ]]; then exit 1; fi
```

Comment: This is a great shout, I will try this out. Have been running into issues using bash to analyse the return from `describe-clusters` and using the cluster name

Comment: Make sure to set the output format to something that's easier to parse.